# How to build a view object in Rails for JavaScript use

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, decorator, active-model-serializers, react-rails

What I'm trying to achieve is to use a decorator (maybe [Draper](https://github.com/drapergem/draper)) to build an object before passing it to my React code (using the [React Rails](https://github.com/reactjs/react-rails) gem). I can easily decorate an object and use the methods in a view, but that is not possible if I pass an array through React props:

`<%= react_component('Project', { name: project.name, choices: project.options %>`

I won't be able access the decorated `project.options.total` method in my JavaScript code.

Is there another way of building these objects? I was using [Active Model Serializers](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers) in the past, but this is not a single page app, it's just a React component inside a Rails view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution would be to create a method that adds the required fields to to a JSON string before it gets passed to the React component.

I think I managed to find a cleaner solution by using [Active Model Serializers](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers). You create a serializer and build the JSON in your controller method:

```
@project_json = ActiveModelSerializers::SerializableResource.new(@projects).as_json
```

As a side note, adding the `current_user` to that serializer can be easily done by using a scope:

```
ActiveModelSerializers::SerializableResource.new(@projects, scope: current_user, scope_name: :current_user).as_json
```